# How to find data range dynamically in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I'm trying to implement data validation in Excel using VBA. I'm able to implement data validation before save excel event but I'm having trouble in finding range, where user gave the input in excel.

For example, I want to implement data validation from A1:C50 but if user enters data from A1:C45, remaining cells will fail due to validations. SO I want to find range A1:C45 and do validations.

Can you please let me know how can I find user data range in Excel?

Comment: Please add your VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly you only want test the data if the row above it has been filled in. If so, you can do this without VBA. In your data validation select 'Custom' and enter the formula below (example for cell A46):

```
=AND(A46>0, A46<=10, COUNTBLANK(A45)=0)
```

This will check for a value between one and ten but only if there is an entry in the row above.

If this doesn't help please provide more information around your question.